# Receiving a malloc error when running a simple client program

Tags: c, client, client-server, malloc

I am trying to test a client program to make sure that it correctly sends and receives messages from a server.  When I run the program I get this weird error from malloc.  Any help would be great.  I've been looking at this code for way too long.  Thanks in advance.
Here is the error:

// The first test runs okay

```
TEST 1 :
Connected to server
 -> Socket open success
 -> Request sent success
 -> Response received success
Testing print:
Response received: <replyLoadAvg>0.228027:0.250000:0.280273</replyLoadAvg>

LoadAvg for 1min :: 0.228027
LoadAvg for 5min :: 0.250000
LoadAvg for 15min :: 0.280273
Real response -> <replyLoadAvg>0.228027:0.250000:0.280273</replyLoadAvg>
```

// Then I get this error for some reason

```
clientc(17781) malloc: ********* error for object 0x7fd048404318: incorrect checksum for        
freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
********* set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

here is the client code:

```
// prototype

char* verifyString(char*);

void printLoadAvg(char*);

int receiveResponse(int, char **);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd;
    char *name;
    char *port;
    struct sockaddr_in * dest;

    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Not enough arguments -- Exiting program\n");
        return 0;
    }

    name = argv[1];
    port = argv[2];

    char * received;
    char send[256];

    char testMessages[5][256] = {"<loadavg/>", "<echo>Hello World!</echo>", "<echo>                        </echo>", "", "<echo>Bye Bye World...<echo>"};
    char expectedResponses[5][256] = {"", "<reply>Hello World!</reply>", "<reply></reply>","<error>unknown format</error>", "<error>unknown format</error>"};

    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("\nTEST %i", i+1);
        printf(((rand() % 2) ? ":\n" : " :\n"));
        sprintf(send, "%s", testMessages[i]);
        sockfd = createSocket(name, atoi(port), &dest);
        if(sockfd < 0){
            printf(" xx Open socket failed\n");
        }
        else{
            printf(" -> Socket open success\n");
            if(sendRequest(sockfd, send, dest) < 0){
                printf(" xx Send failed\n");
            }
            else{
                printf(" -> Request sent success\n");
                if(receiveResponse(sockfd, &received) < 0){
                    printf(" xx Receive failed\n");
                }
                else{
                    printf(" -> Response received success\n");
                    if(i!=0 && strcmp(received, expectedResponses[i]) != 0){
                        printf("Incorrect message\n");
                        printf("Expected: %s\n", expectedResponses[i]);
                        printf("Received: %s\n", received);
                    }
                    else if(i!=0){
                        printf("Test %i. passed successfully!\n", i+1);
                    }
                    else{
                        printf("Testing print:\n");
                        printResponse(received);
                        fprintf(stdout, "Real response -> %s\n", received);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        free(received);
        free(dest);

        if(closeSocket(sockfd)==0){
            printf(" -> Socket closed success\n");
        }
        else{
            printf(" XX Close failed\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


int createSocket( char* hostname, int port, struct sockaddr_in** dest)
{
    // fill in the socket address struct
    (*dest) = (struct sockaddr_in *)malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    struct hostent *hostptr;
    hostptr = gethostbyname(hostname);
    int socketfd;

    memset((void *) (*dest), 0, (size_t)sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    (*dest)->sin_family = (short)(AF_INET);
    memcpy((void*)& (*dest)->sin_addr, (void *) hostptr->h_addr, hostptr->h_length);
    (*dest)->sin_port = htons((u_short)port);

    // now get the file descriptor for the socket
    if((socketfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
            return -1;
    }

    // connect to the server at the location displayed by TCPserver.c
    if(connect(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*)(*dest), sizeof(struct sockaddr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error: call to connect()\n");
        return -1;
    }

        printf("Connected to server\n");

    return socketfd;
}


int sendRequest(int sock, char* request, struct sockaddr_in* dest)
{
    // send a request through the socket to the server.
    if(write(sock, request, BUFFERSIZE) < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    } 

    return 0;
}

int receiveResponse(int sock, char ** response)
{
    // dynamically allocate memory to be used in this function
    (*response) = malloc(sizeof(char));

    // wait for a response from the server
    if(read(sock, (*response), BUFFERSIZE) < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int closeSocket(int sock) 
{
    int error = 0;

if(close(sock)) 
    {
        perror("Error: Failed to close socket\n");
        error = -1;
    }

    return error;

}

void printResponse(char* response)
{
    char* buffer = "<replyloadavg>";
    int i, isLoadAvg = 0;

    // verify the string is in the correct format by calling the verifty string function
    // then print the string to the screen. 
    printf("Response received: %s\n", verifyString(response));

        for(i = 0; i < 14; i++) 
        {
            if(response[i] == buffer[i])
                isLoadAvg = 0;
            else 
            {
                isLoadAvg = 1;
                i = 15;
            }
        }

        if (isLoadAvg) 
        {
            printLoadAvg(response);
        }
    }

char* verifyString(char* string)
{
    int i, count = 0;

    // step through the array until you come to the last '>' (the end of the string)
    // then insert the NULL terminator at the end of the string. 
    for(i = 0; i < BUFFERSIZE; i++)
    {
        if(string[i] == '>')
            count++;
        if(count == 2)
        {
           string[i + 1] = '\0';
            i = BUFFERSIZE;
        }
    }

    return string;
}

void printLoadAvg(char* string)
{
    int i = 0, j;

    // these three arrays hold the newly formated strings, the ones that are easier to read.
    char s1[BUFFERSIZE], s2[BUFFERSIZE], s3[BUFFERSIZE];

    // step through the string until you reach the end of the string
    while(string[i] != '>')
    {
        i++;
    }

    i++;

    // now insert a colon and then save the contents of the string to the appropriate s array.
    for(j = 0; string[i] != ':'; j++, i++)
    {
        s1[j] = string[i];
    }

    // be sure to set the null terminator at the end.
    s1[j] = '\0';
    i++;

    for(j = 0; string[i] != ':'; j++, i++)
    {
        s2[j] = string[i];
    }

   // be sure to set the null terminator at the end.
    s2[j] = '\0';
    i++;

    // now move to the beginning of the end of the string array
    for(j = 0; string[i] != '<'; j++, i++)
    {
       s3[j] = string[i];
    }

    // now insert one more null terminator for the final s array.
    s3[j] = '\0';

    // now print out the newly fomrated strings.
    printf("\nLoadAvg for 1min :: %s\n", s1);
    printf("LoadAvg for 5min :: %s\n", s2);
    printf("LoadAvg for 15min :: %s\n", s3);

}
```

Comment: In `receiveResponse`, did you mean `(*response) = malloc(sizeof(char));`  It seems like that ought to be `(*response) = malloc( BUFFERSIZE );`

Answer (score 1):

```
(*response) = malloc(sizeof(char));

// wait for a response from the server
if(read(sock, (*response), BUFFERSIZE) < 0)
```

What size is `BUFFERSIZE`. Is it bigger than 1? If so, you will overflow your buffer...

Comment: BUFFERSIZE = 256.  This is the maximum possible size of the message being sent.

Comment: Yes, so your malloc probably shoult be `256`, not `1` (sizeof(char) is always `1`). Overwriting the end of buffers gotten from `malloc` is almost certainly what causes the problem in your code. I didn't see any other `malloc` calls, but I may have missed something. Check all calls to `malloc` and make sure the size is sufficient for what you are sticking in the buffer.

Comment: Thank for you that obvious mistake that I definitely should have seen.  Some times it takes another pair of eyes.

Comment: Absolutely. Even a puppet, dog or girlfriend/boyfriend/pet fish will do fine for "explaining the code" at times - but you need to really explain it to someone else. Or have someone else look at the code.